# MySQL: Using a group of columns as ID (SKU)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm developing a item stock system and having some issues with database design.

My `inventory` table lists items in stock.
Each item is unique and identified by a SKU of type `"x-y-z"`, with `x`,`y`,`z` being fields of my table.

Eg:

```
+----------------------------------+
|x     |y     |z     |sku          |
+----------------------------------+
|10    |21    |xs    |10-21-xs     |
+----------------------------------+
|43    |1032  |xl    |43-1032-xl   |
+----------------------------------+
|73    |623   |l     |73-623-l     |
+----------------------------------+
```

I need to be able to find items by their SKU, but also need to return rows for a given `x`,`y` or `z`.

Is there the need to store `sku` along with `x`,`y`,`z` given the fact that `sku` is redundant?

If there is way to avoid this, how would I be able to find items by sku with laravel like this:

```
Item::find(sku); //sku has to be primary key
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't know if Laravel allows it, but MySQL allows you to have multiple columns in a primary key: `PRIMARY KEY (x, y, z)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it is redundant, then you don't need it. The word itself implies it. Look at this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE x||'-'||y||'-'||z = sku;
```

sku is the value you are looking for. Sometimes it can still be good because of performance.

Or alternatively split the string sku and compare x, y, z.

Comment: if this doesn't apply to laravel i will remove

Answer (score 0):

You should save the SKU as well, unless you know for sure x, y, z or the SKU will never ever change.

At any rate, you mignt want to save the SKU (in a column or separate table), the other columns (x,y,z) in that separate table, and identify products by auto incrementing INT's. (more details on that [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15897/mysql-int-vs-varchar-as-primary-key-innodb-storage-engine))

Example:

Products:

```
id | the_rest_of_your_product_columns
_____________________________________
1  | ...
2  | ...
```

Product details:

```
product_id | x | y | z | ...
____________________________
1          | 2 | 3 | 4 | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like you could use a view to define x, y, and z:

```
create table inventory (
    sku varchar(255) not null primary key
);

create view v_inventory as
    select sku, substring_index(sku, '-', 1) as x,
           substring_index(substring_index(sku, '-', 2), '-', 1) as y,
           substring_index(sku, '-', -1) as z
    from inventory;
```

You can then access the `x`, `y`, and `z` values in a `where` clause that uses `v_inventory`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I will keep `sku` separate column and add `unique index` into it. You can do it in `migrations`

```
$table->unique('sku');
```

source http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-indexes

---

Normally Laravel will assume `id` is the primary column name., But you can overwrite it by putting this code in your model

```
class Staff extends Model {

  protected $primaryKey = 'sku';

}
```

source http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage

After you overwrite, you can use `sku` to find your product `$item = Item::find(sku);`